# Access sensors of PowerX H61 motherboard

Tags: sensors

I have recently bought a motherboard of the PowerX model having an Intel H61 chipset -- [this one](https://www.power-x.in/products/power-x-motherboard-pmb-h61-ddr3).
I ran the `sensors` command and it shows only the CPU temperatures. Fan speed is not available. Running `sensors-detect` did not help. By looking at the hardware, I can see there are 4 pins for the CPU fan, so reading fan speed & PWM control should work.
On another motherboard, I got the CPU fan speed and could also control the fan speed. Looks like Linux has less support for the PowerX motherboard or the appropriate drivers are not loaded.

How can I manually probe the motherboard for sensors and PWM controls? Is there any online documentation available for this motherboard?

Comment: Wow! I would never have expected that there's regional mainboard manufacturers! Interesting! Power-X seems to be *purely* aimed at the Indian subcontinent!

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying the boot option `acpi_enforce_resources=lax` and then running `sensors-detect` again.

The ACPI firmware might have marked the monitoring chip as "reserved for motherboard resources", and modern Linux kernels obey such restrictions more strictly than was normal back when H61-based designs were new.

If the `acpi_enforce_resources=lax` allows a sensor chip to be detected, it means the firmware might theoretically access the sensor chip at any time too; however, on a basic desktop motherboard the firmware is unlikely to actually do much with it after initially setting it up at boot time.

Comment: oooh I had forgotten that was a thing. 'doh!

Answer (score 0):

Such sensors are almost universally attached via SMBus or are part of the intel chipset – and both inherently allow devices to enumerate themselves.

So, if it's not detected, I'd assume it simply not *there*. Not much you can do!

> Looks like Linux has less support for the PowerX motherboard or the appropriate drivers are not loaded.

How that works in PCs is usually that you don't need support for a specific mainboard, but for the components on it. That mainboard is pretty obsolete, DDR3 with a platform controller (H61) from early 2011. Not even USB 3.0! So, if any components are not supported, then that probably won't happen anymore.

> Is there any online documentation available for this motherboard?

You'll have to ask the company that sold you this, not us. But I don't think documentation will help you much here. At best, that would be a PDF manual for a user. You'd want developer/integrator documentation for the platform.

I doubt such a thing exists. These guys are so professional, they host the driver packages on a free Google Drive account. They sell counterfeit Apple MacBook displays through their website. The H61 is a long-obsolete chipset that was even in 2011, when it was released, the lowest end of entry level. Someone selling this today has no interest in keeping extensive files, or in long-term customer support.